# Comparing Strings in Python 3

Tags: python, parsing, semantics, repeat

I am writing this little python program that will get new posts on the website www.fmylife.com and I want this program to print these new posts. An easy task even though I just started, but for some reason I cannot get the code to stop printing the same post.

```
import urllib.request,time

def getFml():
    rawfml = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.fmylife.com")
    refml = rawfml.read()
    fml = refml.decode("utf8")
    rawfml.close()
    return fml
def parseFml(fml):
    fml=fml.split('Today,')
    fml=fml[1]
    for char in fml:
        if char in '0123456789<>/="#()-;:"\',':
            fml=fml.replace(char,'')
    fml=fml.split('FMLapdiv')
    fml=fml[0]
    fml=fml.split('aa')
    fml=''.join(fml)
    return fml
    listy=   ['date','left_parta','votej','idvotea','onclickvote','jTipa','comments','right_partp','fmllink','clear','post','hrefwork','class','dyn','javascript','div','classright_partp','hrefmiscellaneous','classdyncomments''div','article','idpa','classclear','classpost','hreflove','classfmlling','FMLap','classdate','classleft_parta','id_','nameresume','classjTipa','span','classdyn-commentsspan','classright_partpspan','classdyn-vote-j','idcotea','hrefjavascript;:','classfmllink','href']
for x in range(len(listy)):
    fml=fml.replace(listy[x],'')
    return fml
oldfml=''
count=0
while True:
    fml=getFml()
    fml=parseFml(fml)
    count=count+1
    if count>1:
        oldfml=fml

    if oldfml == fml:
        time.sleep(300)
    else:
        print('Today,'+fml)
        time.sleep(300)
```

My expected output was to get the post (which I did) and to print it. That works fine. The only problem is that I only want it to print the post once, and when it regularly checks up on the website it is getting printed multiple times and I do not know why.
Thanks To everyone in advance!

Comment: What is your expected output? What do you get? Also, please use an actual parser to parse the HTML, splitting the string is fragile at best. You are also returning nothing from `parseFml()`, just to name a few things from a quick look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of your code:

```
while True:
    fml=getFml()
    fml=parseFml(fml)
    count=count+1
    if count>1:
        oldfml=fml
    if oldfml == fml:
        ...
```

You assign `oldfml=fml` **before** you check their equality. Thus, they are **always** equal.

I suggest the following fix:

```
while True:
    if count>1:
        oldfml=fml
    count=count+1
    fml=getFml()
    fml=parseFml(fml)
    if oldfml == fml:
        ...
```

This way, `oldfml` will actually be old.

Comment: I see what your getting at,but for some reason It still keeps repeating. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Tazzer: Are you certain that the website didn't actually change? If they're different, it should get printed, right? Also, please fix the indentation of your code, right now it's hard to see what parseFml actually does.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion I changed what you told me and It was still printing it twice but then I noticed that 'if count>1' should instead be 'if count>=1' so that it would notice it the first time through as well. Thank you.